# Need to setup a comprehensive e-commerce page for the first time--Magento?

Tags: php, css, e-commerce

I'm a designer (starting to learn PHP/MySQL) and am need in an eCommerce platform (it does **not** have to be free) that will allow me to create a comprehensive eCommerce site--countdown promotions, related products, user reviews, payment/shipping processing, etc. *Basically just populating it with products, and styling the pages.*

I'd appreciate some suggestions for what platforms to explore, that will have either fairly straight forward implementation (for someone with basic PHP knowledge) or documentation with tutorials.

I've heard some buzz around Magento, but I only have experience setting up an Amazon WebStore... which brings me to my next point; seeing as I will be maintaining the page myself, I'm not interested in a clumsy drag-'n'-drop widget front-end design control panel.  Ideally I'd be able to style everything with CSS, and insert/rearrange snippets of PHP code to create each page's design.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is off-topic for Stack Overflow, since it's more a search for recommendation, rather than about coding. You might find it a better fit for Superuser.com or, maybe, webapps.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just learning php/mysql then you'd better stay away from magento for now. It is fairly complex and complicated to maintaing even for experienced developers. The skinning mechanism is also quite complex with a lot of xml layout definitions.

If you are just starting with ecommerce you should look at a simpler shopping cart system. The ones I heard good stuff about are zencart and cubecart. Have a look at wikipedia's [list of ecommerce software solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software) to find the shopping cart which is suited to your needs.

Comment: I'm a fairly quick learner, and code savvy -- but that I'm glad to have your input; Magento very well may be too complex to be worth using, but Zencart and Cubecart pages all look tacky/templated.

I need to be able to customize the layout, and really take leaps away from the templated/cheesy look.  Magento unfortunately has some great looking demo pages, unlike a lot of the other solutions I've looked at.  Would it be worth getting a guide book for Magento?

I need the result to look professional and take advantage of my years of design expertise; I'll continue to look through the wiki list.